how to get document id in appwrite
I need to get the document id which is in the below pic as taskId , but my api is retrieving the projectId as taskId any idea how to fix it appwrite console image
i tried with doing console log and got to know that i was getting projectId
below is my client.tsx code
"use client"

import { PageError } from "@/components/page-error"
import PageLoader from "@/components/page-loader"
import { useGetTask } from "@/features/tasks/api/use-get-task"
import { useTaskId } from "@/features/tasks/hooks/use-task-id"

export const TaskIdClient = () => {
    const taskId = useTaskId()
    const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetTask({ taskId }) 
    console.log('TaskId:', taskId);
    console.log('Error:', error);
    console.log('Data:', data);
    console.log("Data structure:", data);

    if (!taskId) {
        return <PageError message="Invalid Task ID" />
    }
    
    if (error) {
        console.error("Fetch error:", error);
        return <PageError message={error.message || "An unexpected error occurred"} />
    }
    
    if (isLoading) {
        return <PageLoader />
    }
    
    return (
        <p>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    )
}

useGetTask code :
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { client } from "@/lib/rpc"

interface useGetTaskProps {
    taskId: string,

}
export const useGetTask = ({ taskId }: useGetTaskProps) => {
    const query = useQuery({
        queryKey: ["task", taskId],
        queryFn: async () => {
            const res = await client.api.tasks[":taskId"].$get({
                param: {
                    taskId
                }
            });
            console.log("Raw response:", res);
            
            if (!res.ok) {
                const errorMessage = await res.text();
                console.error("Error fetching task:", errorMessage);
                throw new Error("Failed to fetch task");
            }
            
            const data = await res.json();
            console.log("Fetched data:", data); 
            return data;
        }
    });
    return query;
}

and for useTaskId
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";

export const useTaskId = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    return params.taskId as string; 
}

